# как сделать миниатюру окна консоли с моментальным реагированием на изменение кода

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

На одном из курсов по JavaScript у препода увидел вот такое окно (извиняюсь за качество, лучше нету), и очень заинтересовался, как сделать также в VSCode? Я заинтересовался именно двумя миниатюрными окнами справа, а именно тем, что в миниатюрное окно консоли результат выводится моментально при любом редактировании кода в index.js, тоесть человек начинает набирать и результат сразу же меняется в консоли. Может у VSCode тоже есть такая функция?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно очень похоже на VSCode , но как я понял это Codespaces GitHub, который в свою очередь основан на VSCode.

Comment: на сколько я знаю браузер в vscode нельзя выводить, но если открыть параллельно воспользовавшись `live-server` расширением, то как раз он обеспечит при обновлении кода перезапуск страницы и соответственно того что выводится в консоль браузера. Создаете html, подключаете к нему js, открываете html в `live-server` правой кнопкой по файлу, далее меняя html или js будете видеть обновления но необходимо сохранять, можно настроить чтобы сохранялось само - но это быстро убьет Ваш жесткий диск, подумайте надо ли оно Вам.

Comment: А на скрине как раз над миниатюрой консоли вторая миниатюра , это как раз браузер

Answer (score 2):

1. Необходимо на левой панели VSCode перейти в "Расширения"

[image: Левая панель VSCode]

2. Найти и установить расширение "Live Server"

[image: Установка расширения Live Server в VSCode]

3. Создать два файла index.html и index.js. Файл index.js подключить к index.html

[image: Файл index.html и index.js в VSCode]

4. Не покидая файл index.html жмем на кнопку "Go Live" которая находится в правом нижнем углу программы VSCode

[image: Нижняя панель VSCode с кнопкой Go Live]

5. Откроется браузер с Вашей страницей index.html. В браузере жмете комбинацию клавиш <kbd>Gtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> откроется панель " Инструменты разработчика" выбираем вкладку "Консоль". Теперь когда Вы будете писать код в файле index.js и сохранять его нажав комбинацию клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> результат будет отображаться в консоли в реальном времени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну лайв сервер это отдельное окно, а тут все в одном окне
Плюс лайв сервер отразит изменение только тогда, когда сохранишь проект

Comment: @Abraziv777 может в том редакторе это и возможно, но помните чудес не бывает просто файл сохраняется автоматически, и от вашего SSD через год будет ветошь

Comment: @Abraziv777  Если Вы не хотите сохранять изменения вручную Вы всегда можете зайти в главное меню программы "Файл" и в контекстном меню выбрать "Автосохранение"

Answer (score 0):

нашёл что за ресурс на скрине, это stackblitz а не VSCode